Where are events related to certificates logged in Windows?
I need to check which application is installing or deleting a certificate in the Windows certificate store. Is there a an event ID related to this. Should I enable any event auditing policy for this to be logged ?

For the host, check event log Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System/Operational.
Event Id 1006 will be present when a certificate is installed.
Event Id 1004 will be present when a certificate is deleted.
Event Id 1003 will be present when a certificate is approaching expiration.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/technet-wiki/14250.certificate-services-lifecycle-notifications

@GreagAskew I only have events of - ID 1004. Also unable to find the process responsible for installation / deletion of the certificate

This is easy to reproduce by installing a certificate. Are you referring to a user certificate? That is in a separate event log.

I am referring to the certificates stored in both user and system locations. How can I trace back the installation or deletion source? I want to identify the executable responsible for both events. For example, if I install a certificate 'x' using test.exe, where can I find traces related to the installation of 'x' by test.exe or something similar?

You should update the question to include what you are trying to do.
